# ¿como paso data-id a una variable php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

tengo una tabla que lleno desde una base de datos en esta tabla tengo una columna con un  donde al darle click me debe salir una tabla en forma de modal donde estén datos del registro de esa fila,el problema es que no se como pasar el idenficador de esa fila para hacer la consulta a mi base de datos, el identificador lo guardo en un data-id,gracias

**codigo**

```
 <?php  
  include_once('../application/variables_globales.php');

  include_once('../application/conexion.php');
  include_once('../models/tratamientoModel.php');
  include_once('../models/asistenciaModel.php');
  include_once('../models/visitaModel.php');

  $cod_centro =$_GET['cod_centro'];
  $tipo_usuario = $_SESSION['usuario']['cargous'];
  $nombre_usuario = $_SESSION['usuario']['nombre'];


  $pacientes_pares_visistas = lista_pacientes_pares_visitas($enlace, $cod_centro);

 // var_dump($pacientes_pares_visistas);
?>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>N° DE ORDEN</th>
        <th>DNI </th>
        <th>CASO</th>
        <th>PACIENTE</th>
        <th>NUMERO DE VISITAS</th>       
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php  
     $i=1;
      foreach ($pacientes_pares_visistas  as $fila) 
        {
           ?>
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $fila['dni']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $fila['nro_caso']; ?></td>   
                <td align="center"><?php echo $fila['nombre']." ".$fila['apellido_paterno']." ".$fila['apellido_materno']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $fila['dni']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalVisita" ><?php echo $fila['cntidad_visitas']; ?></a></td>
                <td align="center"></td>                   
              </tr>
            <?php
         }         
    ?>    
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="myModalVisita" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">VISITAS PROGRAMADAS</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('#myModalVisita').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {    

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: No se donde guardas el data-id y tampoco esta el codigo donde cargas la modal. Agrega ambas cosas para que sea mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: No se ve por ningún lado donde asignas esa propiedad "data-id"

Comment: gracias ya agrege lo que faltaba,espero su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

1) Agrega una clase en el hyperlink que dispara el Modal. por ejemplo      `class="miClass"`

2) Por JQuery capturamos el click en .miClass y asignamos el valor del data-id al elemento que queramos dentro del Body del Modal. (agregar ID al elemento donde se va a mostrar la informacion).

```
id="idData"
```

Utilizando JQuery hariamos algo como lo siguiente:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".miClass, function () {
        var data = $(this).data('id');
        $(".modal-body #idData").val( data );
 });
```